# Website suddenly dysfunctional

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to work on Wordpress website that hasn't been updated in quite some time. All the sudden there are some weird issues:

• The footer is not linking
• The contact forms are no longer linking
• Half the layout is missing on some pages

Nothing has been changed on this site. No plugins have been updated... nothing.

I've been looking through the coding, and I can't seem to find what's going wrong or why the contact forms have stopped working.

The website is Marshcreek.com
Please help!

Comment: Looking good for me? I mean, I do not see a footer in the HTML, so it can't be showed either?

Comment: Have you tried updating your plugins, website, etc? You would need to provide some actual code for anyone to help, we can't see the PHP.

Comment: Wordpress is not famous by it security, so maybe your WP version have a security breach that was explored by someone...

Comment: you updated WP to a fairly new version ( not latest ) 3.7.1. that version uses a new `jQuery`. are you sure your plugin / theme are compatible ??

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup, run a file comparison between the current copy and the backup. My files have been purged in the past through unfortunate maintenance routines.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend speaking with your Host and ask them if they have upgraded / changed anything on the server?

I have however noticed the following, the first image is the HTML from the index
[image: index-page]

And this is the HTML from the Memberships page?
[image: membership]

at the bottom there is 4 `<div style="clear:both"></div>`? Is this how it should be because this may explain where the footer has gone in this example!

Also if you have any backups of the site you may wish to take a look at them as they may help recover some of the structure